# Woocommerce custom discount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know if it is possible to give a customer in a certain group a discount on products with a specific tag.

**Pseudocode:**

```
If $user_role=X && product_tag=Y; 
{
 discountprice=$productprice * $discountpercentage 
}
```

I would like to do this for multiple producttags and multiple roles.

Is there a plugin for this?

Comment: try below https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-role-discount/5382490 and https://wisdmlabs.com/woocommerce-user-specific-pricing-extension/ plugin

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The plugins you mentioned do not combine the product tag and the role to get to a price. The plugin form wisdmlabs does give a discount sitewide but you have to set it up per product and the codecanyon plugin does not look at a product tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. If someone else is looking for the solution: I changed the taxonomy from product_tag to product_cat in the term_taxonomy table. 
Then I used this plugin:
https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-pricing